Is there a way to render a number of the same component with Flatlist rather than data?
I am trying to render multiple cards within a Flatlist, where the number of cards to be rendered is set in state. I don't know if there is a way to accomplish this since, to my knowledge, Flatlist only takes an array in its data attribute.
Here's what I'm trying to do:
[numberOfCards, setNumberOfCards] = useState(1)

<FlatList
  horizontal
  pagingEnabled
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  data={numberOfCards}
  renderItem={({ card }) => {
    return (
      <Card />
    );
  }}
/>


yes you can render a number without using an array of data. create an array with what you want to render create a function that defines the rendering.
Pass the generated array as the data prop to FlatList. Set the renderItem prop to your rendering function, which will specify how each item should be displayed.
Ensure that each item in the array has a unique key by using the index or another unique identifier. This helps React efficiently update the list
I might be able to find a example code if needed
